# Sealing/resurfacing exterior concrete retaining wall

Tags: concrete, exterior, mold, retaining-wall, sealant

I have a 3 ft concrete retaining wall that runs across our backyard. It collects a lot of black mildew with white spots. Is there a sealant or other surfacing material that I can use to help keep clean? I live near Vancouver, BC.

Comment: At 1 house I collected some moss that was growing on some rocks blended it in a mixer with some milk and brushed it on a retaining wall the moss looked great most of the year I would even spray it with a hose in the late summer to keep it green, with the moss it looks more natural at least here in the Pacific Northwest. About 6 months after selling the home the new owner called and asked if I knew there was wall in the front yard, I told him yes if you water it it will stay green after stripping some of the moss his wife told him to quit and let it grow back, my wife told them the milk trick.